# GPS (USB) with NTP has a consistantly large offset and high jitter from public NTP sources

Tags: usb, gps, pi-b+, ntp

I have a Raspberry Pi Model B Rev 2 (BCM2835 rev 000e). Connected to it is a USB G-Mouse GPS receiver - which is really just a u-blox 7 GPS receiver. I've had it running for about 15 hours now and it still reports time that is significantly off from public NTP sources. As far as I can tell, I will have to [do some soldering](https://magazine.odroid.com/article/creating-ntp-server-using-gps-pps/) to get PPS source working correctly, but my understanding is that GPS is what provides the time source even with PPS working - so I'm not sure what is going wrong with my setup. Currently, the GPS offset is `-49.017` with public time sources being `16.591` - so there is a large gap between them.

GPSD Settings:

```
# /etc/default/gpsd

START_DAEMON="true"
USBAUTO="true"
DEVICES="/dev/ttyACM0"
GPSD_OPTIONS="-n"
```

NTP settings:

```
# GPS Serial data reference (NTP0)
server 127.127.28.0
fudge 127.127.28.0 time1 0.0 refid GPS

# GPS PPS reference (NTP1)
server 127.127.28.1 prefer
fudge 127.127.28.1 refid PPS
```

Running `gpsmon` - everything looks good to me. With 9 satellites at the moment.

[image: gpsmon output]

Output from `ntpq -c rv -pn`

```
associd=0 status=0418 leap_none, sync_uhf_radio, 1 event, no_sys_peer,
version="ntpd 4.2.8p12@1.3728-o (1)", processor="armv6l",
system="Linux/4.19.75+", leap=00, stratum=1, precision=-19,
rootdelay=0.000, rootdisp=3.489, refid=GPS,
reftime=e1b9c988.b348e9c2  Fri, Jan  3 2020 14:09:12.700,
clock=e1b9c9c3.22ea8839  Fri, Jan  3 2020 14:10:11.136, peer=57008, tc=6,
mintc=3, offset=-1.475171, frequency=-27.690, sys_jitter=0.000000,
clk_jitter=1.693, clk_wander=0.107, tai=37, leapsec=201701010000,
expire=202006280000

     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
*127.127.28.0    .GPS.            0 l   59   64  377    0.000   -1.475   1.836
 127.127.28.1    .PPS.            0 l    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
```

On a second device, which I have setup as an NTP client - it shows that the time is off (`ntpq -c rv -pn`) (192.168.4.30 is the pi with GPS):

```
associd=0 status=0615 leap_none, sync_ntp, 1 event, clock_sync,
version="ntpd 4.2.8p10@1.3728-o Sat Mar 10 18:03:33 UTC 2018 (1)",
processor="armv7l", system="Linux/4.19.66-v7+", leap=00, stratum=3,
precision=-21, rootdelay=55.738, rootdisp=37.157, refid=107.155.79.108,
reftime=e1b9c9ab.6602a854  Fri, Jan  3 2020  9:09:47.398,
clock=e1b9ca29.2de7f8c7  Fri, Jan  3 2020  9:11:53.179, peer=19769,
tc=10, mintc=3, offset=17.376459, frequency=-1.665, sys_jitter=3.848777,
clk_jitter=28.916, clk_wander=0.076
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
+192.168.4.1     69.89.207.99     2 u  140 1024  377    0.546   16.713   6.773
-192.168.4.30    .GPS.            1 u  915 1024  377    0.848  -49.017   4.665
 0.debian.pool.n .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 1.debian.pool.n .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 2.debian.pool.n .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 3.debian.pool.n .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 0.pool.ntp.org  .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 1.pool.ntp.org  .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 2.pool.ntp.org  .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 3.pool.ntp.org  .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
+108.61.56.35    198.30.92.2      2 u  182 1024  377   36.456   19.257   7.304
*107.155.79.108  129.7.1.66       2 u  126 1024  377   48.246   16.591   6.812
+23.31.21.163    252.74.143.178   2 u  148 1024  377   44.590   17.076   6.954
-104.236.116.147 128.59.0.245     2 u   56 1024  377   35.528   21.247   6.805
```

Comment: Here's [something to ponder](https://www.masterclock.com/company/masterclock-inc-blog/network-synchronization-internet-ntp-servers-vs-gps-ntp-servers)

Comment: Yes, I always think that GPS is what gives you the reliable real time clock signal. You might like to compare my GPS time record in Appendix M of my answer to the following GPS question: GPS Setup and Data (Appendix M shows time signal)
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98840/rpi-uart-to-gps-module-connection-problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So...a couple of things. Firstly, "why" you need the PPS...

Let's back up a bit. In the ancient world of the 1970s and 1980s, when one spoke of "the system clock" or of a system's "clock", one did not mean the Time-of-Day Clock---what is nowadays called a Real Time Clock. The system clock was derived from a crystal oscillator that was smoothed out and divided down into a square wave with very, very, uniform characteristics---in those days, producing an 8 MHz system clock was pretty awesome.

So "clocking" a signal---say clocking the Read/Write control signal for a shift register's address lines---meant the periodic application of a control signal, which was a square wave derived from that oscillator---the system clock. This was an electrical implementation of Boolean Arithmetic; those '1' and '0' that get thrown around with abandon these days. A system---be it a single board or a series of refrigerator-sized cases each comprising a piece of the entire "computer"---depended upon this abstraction, and so it had to have a very fine resolution: the difference between a signal set HIGH and a signal set LOW had to be discernible by the components making up the system.

By the 1980s and the dawn of the actual Personal Computer era, this was something that was well-established. For most components, a signal value of 5 Volts DC was accepted as being HIGH, and a signal value of 0 Volts was accepted as being LOW. Right about now, you should be noticing that we're talking about Direct Current Voltages without polarity. That's because the absolute polarity was considered a design decision, not a standard. If one chose to use -5V DC as HIGH, that was what one did---and everything was designed to that reference. Thus systems could perform boolean arithmetic using a value of +/-5 VDC and 0 VDC.

Of course, other bothersome aspects of electrical circuits interfered with that model---there was capacitance and inductance, for example. There was loss associated with temperature, with humidity, with the huge cookie-sized integrated circuits (ICs). There were wave guides---what we now call wires and cables---and taps (connectors) and valves (switches).

And then there's the actual physics of wave forms. If you "dial down" far enough, your square wave isn't. Turns out it has---and here comes a **Really Important Thing**---both a Rising Edge and a Falling Edge. Further complicating what seemed so simple is the sensitivity of individual ICs to changes in voltage; an IC has a *tolerance*, a percentage or fixed amount of the reference signal voltage which is sufficient to force a change in state on its pins.

Naturally, the characteristics of a signal's Rising and Falling Edge(s) combines with the sensitivity of individual ICs to changes in voltage. Thus, once a signal exceeds the HIGH transition threshold, the IC considers any pin receiving that signal to have been "driven HIGH". The same thing happens when driving a signal LOW.

So, in the Bad Old Days, once a signal passed a certain point on it's way to 5V, it "drove" any pin it touched HIGH, and once it passed a certain point on it's way to 0V, it "drove" any pin it touched LOW. As you have probably forseen, all that cluttery junk like wave guides and valves and heat and so forth, tend to make the transition happen at slightly different times at different ICs. This is Not Good. And the better the ICs became, the more Not Good having *latency* became. As 8 MHz gave way to 16 MHz and 24 MHz, and then 32 MHz and 40 MHz (yes, Virginia, 40 MHz really was *fast* once upon a time), latency---the combination of all the factors interfering with the instantaneous change in condition of all the pins in the system---became a serious problem.

It is this issue---the when of a '1' or '0'---that makes bothersome concepts like Rising Edge or Trailing Edge important. What becomes important at clock speeds in the GHz is not just the VDC value of '1' or '0', but *when* in that narrow window a signal is valid.

---

Which brings us back to GPS, NMEA, that pesky PPS, and the idea of System Time of Day as requiring precision. As you probably know, precision in System Time of Day is key for a number of things that actually matter, like the security of the internet and your private information. If you are concerned enough to build your own Reference Clock and run an NTP Server, then you'll want it to keep accurate time with or without external NTP servers.

GPS has time data that is good enough for keeping up with where you are when you are driving your car, riding your bike, or trying to find your glasses (apparently). That is, it's going to give you the same Time Of Day as any other GPS-sourced Time of Day Clock, like, say, the clock in your car.

So...your GPS-USB Reference Clock provides *your* system with the Time of Day *as it was in the satellite when that satellite broadcast the signal your receiver employed to produce its NMEA time message*. Right? **Not The One True Time of Times**, but **a** reliable Time of Day which may be used to compute your location and movement on Earth.

Without a way to synchronise the system clock (at 3 GHz or so) and the Reference Clock, your system---and thus the NTP Daemon---cannot adjust the time from the satellites to the computer to produce a stable, accurate, System Time Of Day. NTP is focused on *accuracy*, not speed of resolution. It will get you a pretty solid System Time Of Day within a day or so. Over a month, it will get you a fantasic System Time Of Day; in six months, NTP will be providing a time more accurate than your computer can actually use.

To do that, though, NTP requires an accurate time source. And for all the reasons I laid out, that absolutely requires that it have access to a Pulse-Per-Second signal that it can understand (the drivers have a flag that tell NTPD which Edge to use).

The chip you are using---the 25mm square IC which now encloses what once required that refrigerator-sized case---does provide a PPS signal. Unfortunately, the board you are using does not connect it to the USB cable, nor mux it into the NMEA messages it sends to GPSD or to the NPTD driver. To check, run your gpsmon again and look in the lower middle of the display---there will be a line "PPS" and it will be followed by nothing. I double checked your cut-and-paste, and you are not getting PPS.

Without that PPS signal, all you can expect from your Reference Clock is rough accuracy on the order you are seeing. Again, the longer NTPD runs against the USB-GPS, the better your accuracy will be, to a point.

Secondly, an assessment of a more fundamental issue:

The other aspect of your predicament is more akin to expecting your Roma Tomato to stand in for your Beefsteak Tomato. Although you can make the one work for the other, why not just get what you want? If you are making a roast beast sandwich, use a Beefsteak Tomato; if you are making a red sauce, use a Roma.

You went to the trouble of creating a Reference Clock and an NTP server, then were dissatisfied because it worked like a Reference Clock and not like an Internet Pool Server. You went in and hacked the driver parameters ("fudge") to force your Reference Clock to give you the same time you get off of the Internet (for the moment). You could have just unplugged the USB GPS and pointed that system at the NTP Pool, too; or pointed it as a Peer at the system with the time you want.

The advantage of having a NTP Server and a Reference Clock for it is to avoid the latencies and irregularities of the internet, and to maximise the accuracy possible for your System Real Time Clock. If you want your system time to match the time given by an Internet Time Server, then run NTPD as a client of that Internet Time Server. If you want accurate time provided by a local NTP Server not subject to the many obstacles presented by the internet, then you need to configure your local NTP Server properly.

The first thing you have to do, to run a working local NTP Server, is set the driver parameters properly for a baseline start. You want to approximate the latency introduced by the Serial Line and the USB-Serial converter. These numbers are available from most manufacturers, but you will have to get the data sheets for the MK series GPS chip and whoever makes the USB-Serial converter. This has been done by several other people, and you could canvas several other NTP projects to get some input if you don't want to dig up the documentation---though you clearly are willing to put in plenty of work, so I'm guessing you'll do both.

Once the reference clock driver is running as it should---whether you are using the serial line driver ('20') or the newer GPSD driver ('46')---you can use ntpd to close the gap between Internet Servers you trust, your GPS input, and what your system believes the time is; recall that a Raspberry Pi has no Real Time Clock.

To get the System Time Of Day close to where you feel confident it should be---those reliable pool servers, for example---use ntpd in "set-and-quit" mode. First, remove the "ntp.drift" file. Next run `sudo ntpd --panicgate --set-debug-level=1` **and** either use a config file pointing at the pool servers `--configfile=/your/ntp.conf`**or** list the servers out on the command line `server1 server2 server3 server4 server5`.

This will take a little while, but the debug level will give you plenty of information on what is happening. When it finishes, it will print a message indicating what System Time of Day set methodology (slew or step) and magnitude was needed.

Now, you can run ntpd using your Reference Clock. Be sure you either have an entry for a drift file in your ntp.config file, or specify it on the command line as `--driftfile=/your/ntp.drift` . In the over-complicated world of Linux, doing so can be non-trivial, FYI.

Without access to the PPS signal, you are probably better off just using the Internet Servers, but, you *could* set up your NTP to use your local Reference Clock as **a** server, and also point at other Internet Servers (like those reliable pool servers). That way the poor performance of USB-Serial GPS only gets dealt with by NTPD, but if your internet connection goes down, you still have some kind of clock reference.

Lastly, you should bear in mind that "a whole day" is not really all that much time to NTP. Your GPS system has a PPS output you could use to jump onto the GPIO pins. Or You could try and figure out why gpsd cannot pick up the PPS data from its driver---theoretically, gpsd is supposed to do all of the work of driving your MTK chip, and so it *should* be able to produce a PPS value in shared memory, although it clearly is **NOT**.

SFH

PS: The gpsd driver can only manipulate data on the USB side of the board, and the board you are using does not wire the PPS signal to a line that is "included" in the serial data converted. The Adafruit MTK-based boards do have the PPS signal available (they didn't just tie it to ground), but for some reason, they did not tie it to the serial interface DCD line ("Carrier Detect"). The Ultimate USB Breakout and the Ultimate Hat both have wire-wrap sockets you could use to get PPS onto the GPIO edge connector---I have a soldering trick that might help you if you don't like to solder, which is on the far (Raspberryu Pi) side of the USB bridge. The Ultimate GPS Hat has breadboarding sockets you could also use.

IF you tie the PPS line to the serial line DCD on the MTK chip-side of the Serial-USB converter---"in front of" the USB Bridge---then the USB Bridge will pass it along, and it will show up in shared memory &c.

PPS: If you just don't do soldering, it IS possible to "strap" the PPS output from one of the Adafruit boards to the Raspberry Pi using only wire-wrap connectors, but you'll need an intermediate board and it's kind of a Frankenstein's Monster---but it does work! Or just buy a more expensive USB GPS source that actually ties a PPS signal to the DCD (there's a list, let me know if you want a pointer to it).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. It’s a lot of information to take in, but I agree that it seems like it’s as good as it can get without the PPS signal working, which is really unfortunate.

Comment: You're welcome...."why" is always tough to answer!

Comment: One more thing...there IS a way to get a PPS signal into the USB signal. You need to get the PPS signal from the MK chip tied to the serial line's DCD pin before the Serial-USB converter; if the USB converter picks up a signal on DCD, it will pass it through to the Raspberry Pi using shared memory, which will let you use the SHM clock driver in NTP. Let me know if you want more info or how-to.

Comment: @lightswitch05, I dug up some more information for you, though I'm still not sure which of the Adafruit USB GPS boards you are using. The Ultimate GPS With USB versus the Ultimate GPS Breakout. See below for some more info.

Comment: Overall great answer with lots of good info, but the part talking about ever increasing accuracy of an NTP client vs time is wrong. 

The dominant factor on local timing is the frequency of the main crystal.  This has an offset, which varies with temperature and also "ages".  During initial lock, NTP calibrates out the offset.  After that point it tracks the ongoing variation using a FLL/PLL.  This dominates long term accuracy.

If you want further improvement you need a OCXO or TCXO https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/74482/switch-out-the-x1-oscillator-on-a-rpi-2-3/117985

Answer (score 1):

I'm unable to determine why the offset is so large. I'm also unsure why the PPS feature is not being exposed through the USB. After opening up the receiver, it appears to have a wire for it, but I can't read it. Also, I'm not great with electrical, so perhaps I'm also wrong.

[image: GPS internals back]

[image: GPS internals front]

Anyways, I do have a solution of sorts. After close monitoring of my GPS offset vs. several different public Stratum 1 servers, I was able to determine a consistent `time1` offset value to line up my GPS time with public sources:

```
server 127.127.28.0 minpoll 3 maxpoll 4 prefer iburst
fudge 127.127.28.0 time1 0.070 refid GPS
```

I came up with the value `0.070` after a lot of monitoring. First, I ran `ntpq -c rv -pn` often to view the offset over several hours. You can also run `watch -n 30 ntpq -c rv -pn` to automatically run it every 30 seconds. This gave me nice feedback and I was able to get a close offset quickly - however, I ended up with `0.080` using this method.

For the more accurate `0.070` value, I needed more a in-depth view of the offset over the course of an entire day. I enabled stats logging by uncommenting this line (debian buster default config already has stats configured correctly, it just needs this one line to be enable to go into effect):

```
statsdir /var/log/ntpstats/
```

That will cause two types of stats to be logged, loopstats and peerstats. I let it run for an entire day without modification or rebooting. After the day was complete, I exported the logs to a windows machine and downloaded a tool called [NTP Plotter](https://www.satsignal.eu/software/net.htm#NTPplotter). With NTP plotter, I was able to generate graphs of my GPS offset vs. the public stratum 1 servers. In the graphs, I noticed I was consistently off and changed the time1 value to `0.070`. After another full day of stats I repeated the process and was pleased with the offsets:

[image: stratum 1 vs GPS offsets]

As you can see in the graph above, my GPS offset stays roughly in the center now compared with the public stratum 1 servers I was using for testing.

Again, I do not understand why I need this offset, perhaps it has to do with delays with the USB and raspberry pi. But setting the `time1` value solved it and I'm pleased that I was able to use statistics over a full day to be able to make an educated decision about the `time1` value instead of just trial and error. I'm marking this as the solution for now, but if anyone comes up with a better method then I would be happy to change the solution.

Comment: I used this to calculate the average time offset `cat /var/log/ntpstats/peerstats* | grep 127.127.28.0 | cut -d ' ' -f 5 | sed 's/\./,/g' | awk '{ s += $1 } END { print "sum: ", s, " average: ", s/NR, " samples: ", NR }'` . sed replaces all dots with commas what may not be needed if your system uses dots for decimals.

Comment: I got the average time offset for `time1` 75,8 ms.

Comment: By using gnuplot it's easier to get more stats. `cat /var/log/ntpstats/peerstats* | grep 127.127.28.0  | cut -d ' ' -f 5 | gnuplot -e 'stats "-" nooutput; print "samples: ", STATS_records, ", mean: ", STATS_mean, ", sample standard deviation: ", STATS_ssd, ", min: ", STATS_min, ", max: ", STATS_max '`

Comment: The offset you're adjusting for is indeed related to delay, but it is for the full stack: USB hardware, USB stack, USB-Serial drivers, Serial reading software, NTP processing software.  This can add up to 10s of ms.

With a PPS signal connected to a GPIO pin (not via USB), you bypass the whole lot, and can set a HW interrupt on the rising edge. Your latency is then simply that of the interrupt handler.

My own NTP setup (https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/74482/switch-out-the-x1-oscillator-on-a-rpi-2-3/117985) uses USB for the NEMA code, but GPIO for PPS.